# ModelSim wave window showing zero time transitions

Tags: verilog, modelsim

I'm new to verilog and so ModelSim. There's a problem or actually may not be a problem that I have noticed.

It seems to me that ModelSim wave window imposes by default a transition at time zero on any signal. Depending on the initial value of the signal it's either a 1 to 0 or a 1 to 0 transition. This may not cause problems for most cases but it might, say with negative-edge triggered circuits whose clock is initially set to 0 and do not expect a zero time triggering. To show the problem consider the following verilog code describing a falling edge triggered DFF:

```
module dff(d,clk,reset,q);

//define DFF delay
`define DFF_DLY 5

input d,clk,reset;
output reg q;

always @(negedge clk or posedge reset)
   if (reset)
      q=#`DFF_DLY 0;
   else
      q=#`DFF_DLY d;

endmodule
```

Based on the following test bench code the output signal q is determined 5ns after an early triggering occurred at time 0ns (the zero time transitions are also visible in the image):

[image]

Test bench code:

```
module dff_tb;

reg d,reset,clk;
wire q;

initial begin
d=1'b1;
clk=1'b0;
reset=1'b0;
end

always #10 clk=~clk;
//always #27 reset=~reset;
always #18 d=~d;

dff ff1(d,clk,reset,q);

endmodule
```

One solution that I think of is modify the module *dff* in such a way that the negative edge triggering happens soon after a positive edge is detected. This prevents an early, unexpected negative triggering. The part of modified code is shown below.

```
always @(posedge clk or posedge reset)
   if (reset)
      q=#`DFF_DLY 0;
   else
      always @(negedge clk) q=#`DFF_DLY d;
```

While the above trick solves the problem this is not actually what I'm looking for. I don't want to modify the code, which works fine in case of no initial transitions. The question: Is that a problem with my test bench code or that's the ModelSim that comes the issue with? In either case how to solve the problem?

Best,

Answer (score 1):

You just need to initialize the clock to a 1 rather than a 0, so the first falling edge will occur at 10ns.

Having said that, in the real world all sorts of bizarre events will occur at t=0, when the power is first turned on. It is quite possible that a falling edge will occur on the clock at this time. Your design should not rely on well-behaved signals at t=0.

Comment: You're right. To have the FF design behave well for real signals my solution seems to work as well. It doesn't rely on the time 0 transitions. However, in terms of logic synthesis I'm afraid it might add complexity to the overall design.

Answer (score 0):

Move to SystemVerilog. Declare all your clocks with the 2-state type 1 `bit`. That eliminates the time 0 X-to-0 transition.

```
module dff(input logic d, bit clk, logic reset,
           output logic q);
`define DFF_DLY 5

always @(negedge clk or posedge reset)
   if (reset)
      q<=#`DFF_DLY 0;
   else
      q<=#`DFF_DLY d;

endmodule
```

---

If you cannot use SystemVerilog, then set the `reset` signal to 1 before making any changes to the clock. Keep reset active until after the clock as a full period.

```
module dff_tb;

reg d,reset=1,clk;
wire q;

initial begin
    d=1'b1;
    #1 clk=0;
    #20 reset = 1;
  end
...
endmodule
```

Comment: Though I wanted a Verilog solution this trick also didn't work with the same test bench code. The time 0 x-to-0 transitions are still there

Comment: Also do we have such transitions in real clocks?

Comment: A signal declared as `bit` cannot have transitions to/from `X`. I've update my answer to show a Verilog-only.

Answer (score -1):

ModelSim generally generates events at time 0 for all signals, and calculates the combinatorial cascade for them so derived signals are initialized correctly.

From a synthesis point of view, it generally does not matter, because initial values don't exist in synthesis and all signals are undefined until the reset mechanism is used.

You want to encourage the compiler to generate an asynchronous reset that is connected to a global high-fanout reset network, and the condition that blocks any synchronous transitions from happening while the reset is asserted does exactly that (because otherwise the asynchronous reset would have to be gated).

On the simulation side, if you want accurate representation, generate the stimuli accordingly. Although that is usually overkill, something equivalent to

```
...
    signal clk : std_logic := '0';
    signal clk_reset_n : std_logic;
    signal reset_n : std_logic;
    signal d, q : std_logic;
begin
    clk <= not clk after 10 ns;
    clk_reset_n <= 'U', '0' after 15 ns, '1' after 35 ns;
    reset_n <= 'U', '0' after 25 ns, '1' after 50 ns;

    dut : entity work.dff
        port map(
            d => d,
            clk => clk and clk_reset_n,
            reset => not reset_n,
            q => q);

    stimuli : process
    begin
        d <= 'U';
        wait for 20 ns;
        d <= '0';
        for i in 1 to 10 loop
            wait for 7 ns;
            d <= not d;
        end loop;
        wait;
    end process;
```

would be somewhat realistic because all the inputs come up as undefined initially, but leave this state before the reset signal is deasserted (as the combinatorial circuits before it settle in response to the reset signal).

It is uncommon to write a testbench like this however, as the configuration sequence will first load the LUTs, then activate inputs, then activate outputs, so if the board correctly asserts the user reset pin during and shortly after configuration, any changes on externally visible outputs will be from the state during configuration to the state in user reset.

This transition cannot be avoided in logic and the surrounding circuitry needs to handle this gracefully (e.g. by ANDing signals with the "configuration done" signal) anyway.

So for the simulation of individual components that means you would assert the user reset at t = 0, which would, in your case, also lead to a deterministic output signal -- and this is where the event generated for the initial value becomes useful: otherwise this initial value would not be processed.